# How to bind the selected item in a KendoUI ListView to a selectedItem property of my observable viewModel?

Tags: listview, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a listview let's say like this:

```
$("#items").kendoListView({
        dataSource: itemsSource,
        selectable: true,
        ...
        change: function () {
            var data = itemsSource.view(),
                selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
                    return data[$(item).index()];
                });
        }
});
```

Then, I have my ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        items: activitiesSource,
        itemTitle: selected.Title,
        itemDescription: "",
        selectedItem: null,
        ...
        hasChanges: false,
        change: function () {
            this.set("hasChanges", true);
        }
});
```

And I have my html code, let's say:

```
<ul id="items" data-bind="source: items, value: selectedItem"></ul>
```

And I want to, when an item is selected in my ListView, to be able to edit the selected item in a form.
If I do something like this, in the ListView change event:

```
viewModel.set("selectedActivity", selected);
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a copy/paste error on your end, but your line:

```
viewModel.set("selectedActivity", selected);
```

The `viewModel` doesn't have a property `selectedActivity`, it is named `selectedItem` instead.

I assume there is another widget or set of html controls bound to the `viewModel.selectedItem` that isn't shown here?